# Building Plone.4-3.14 gives "need more than 0 values to unpack"

Tags: plone, setuptools, easy-install, buildout, feedparser

When running buildout with the Plone-4.3.14-version-configs, the errors below are thrown.

```
Getting distribution for 'feedparser==5.0.1'.
error: Not a recognized archive type: /tmp/tmpuOPdYIget_dist/feedparser-5.0.1.tar.bz2
An error occurred when trying to install /tmp/tmpuOPdYIget_dist/feedparser-5.0.1.tar.bz2. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing instance.
  Getting distribution for 'feedparser==5.0.1'.

An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ida/.virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 2127, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/home/ida/.virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 797, in install
    installed_files = self[part]._call(recipe.install)
  File "/home/ida/.virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1557, in _call
    return f()
  File "/home/ida/.buildout/eggs/plone.recipe.zope2instance-4.2.22-py2.7.egg/plone/recipe/zope2instance/__init__.py", line 114, in install
    installed.extend(self.install_scripts())
  File "/home/ida/.buildout/eggs/plone.recipe.zope2instance-4.2.22-py2.7.egg/plone/recipe/zope2instance/__init__.py", line 618, in install_scripts
    requirements, ws = self.egg.working_set(['plone.recipe.zope2instance'])
  File "/home/ida/.buildout/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-1.3.2-py2.7.egg/zc/recipe/egg/egg.py", line 101, in working_set
    **kw)
  File "/home/ida/.virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 924, in install
    return installer.install(specs, working_set)
  File "/home/ida/.virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 726, in install
    for dist in self._get_dist(req, ws):
  File "/home/ida/.virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 570, in _get_dist
    dists = [_move_to_eggs_dir_and_compile(dist, self._dest)]
  File "/home/ida/.virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 1704, in _move_to_eggs_dir_and_compile
    [tmp_loc] = glob.glob(os.path.join(tmp_dest, '*'))
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a moment to figure out why, because the explanation does not lie in the last error-message, but the preceding one:
`Not a recognized archive type`, which hints that easy_install cannot handle bunzip-files.

It means that the required sys-package `bzip-devel` was not present when installing Python.
So one must either install that package and install Python again, or in this case also commenting out the pin for `feedparser` lets the build run without errors.

Afterwards noticed that feedparser is not in the eggs-cache-dir, as it used to be in another build with same versions-configs. At a glance cannot tell the difference why, but the errors are resolved.

Comment: My vague recollection is that bzip support is simply not compiled in if `bzip-devel` or equivalent packages aren't present at installation time.

Comment: That could be an explanation, not urgent enough to me to test that, but thanks for dropping that info, may be of help for others.

Comment: As I ran again into this, tried your suggestion (in my case for Fedora that was `yum install bzip-devel`) and then needed to freshly install a new Python with the now available lib. There might be a less brutal way, but anyway feel feel to post this as answer, so I can accept it. Thanks for helping!